# Copy paste data from one sheet to any other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I have this code which only copy-paste data from sheet 1 one to sheet 2.

```
Sub CopyPasteCumUpdate()
    Dim rng As Range, inp As Range
    'to remove 0 values that may be a result of a formula or direct entry.
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set inp = Selection
    inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        rng.Parent.Activate
        rng.Select
        inp.Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Is it possible to input data and paste it to any other sheet without having to hard code?

Comment: `Is it possible to input data and paste it to any other sheet without having to hard code` what method do you have in mind? Cause it depends really. How will you tell the routine which sheet to copy to?

Comment: @L42 im not really too sure. the routine will copy to the sheet the user clicks on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment that is easy. Just change this part:

```
rng.Parent.Activate
rng.Select
inp.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
```

With this:
**Edit:** This is to paste the link in the range the user selected.

```
Application.Goto rng
inp.Copy
rng.Parent.Paste Link:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
```

Comment: Can you help me on my prev question as well if possible?Thanks!      @L42

Comment: @Niva I'll try :). Btw, I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! But what is the difference anyway? @L42

Comment: @Niva ah, the edit paste the link on the range selected by the user. Btw, I've commented a possible solution to your other problem. But that is not VBA.