# Create Macro to Copy, Paste for multiple Data sheets

Tags: excel, validation, copy-paste

Below is just a macro I recorded myself which may or may not be helpful. Basically, I am trying to copy the number, name, and date from one sheet (Worksheet) then paste into a different spreasheet (Data Entry Form).

FYI, the number, name, and date goes from left to right on the ‘Worksheet’, and Each row of data (number, name , and date) needs to go into a separate ‘Data Entry Form’.

So I am looking for a macro that will use the data from “Worksheet”  and place it into the ‘Data Entry Form’ while generating additional ‘Data Entry Forms’ (more worksheets) for each separate row of data.
The number of rows in the Worksheet can vary from 10-100 so having a macro would save me ample time of copying and pasting into new forms; even if the macro can only do one row of data at a time.

```
  Sub Popsecform()
'
' Popsecform Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Data Entry form.xlsx").Activate
    Range("F8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("Worksheet.xlsx").Activate
    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Data Entry form.xlsx").Activate
    Range("F30").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("Worksheet.xlsx").Activate
    Range("D2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Data Entry form.xlsx").Activate
    Range("F24").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Edit

I am just trying to create a workbook that will be able to generate my Data Entry Form as an additional sheet to the workbook every time I add another row of Name, Number, and Date to the first Worksheet.

Row A goes to Data Entry Form 1 (Distinct cells)
Row B goes to Data Entry Form 2  (same distinct cells)
and so on

Comment: This might help your problem!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801163/copy-paste-data-from-one-sheet-to-any-other-worksheet

Comment: It def seems similar but I'm trying to copy a specific row of data (3 cells) then paste them into the other sheet to a specific cell on the Data Entry form.

Comment: that code can help copy specific cells and paste it to a specific cell @user1916429

Comment: I get what you're saying but I don't understand the code. I'm a beginner when it comes to macros. I can't see where I can input the cells I need copy (specific range) then placed into the appropriate cells.